# Mandatorio vs Obbligatorio

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Sovente mi capita, in ambito professionale, di leggere documenti interni di analisi del software e trovare il termine ***mandatorio***.

Nell'intento di chi scrive, tale termine indica l'italianizzazione del termine inglese ***mandatory*** che vuol dire ***obbligatorio***.

Ho cercato in rete l'etimologia del termine ma non ho trovato nulla.

A mio avviso l'uso di questo termine è errato e dovrebbe essere sostituito da ***obbligatorio***.

Cosa ne pensate?

Comment: Interessante discussione: http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=819&view=next

Comment: A me piace quel "vs" nel titolo della domanda!

Comment: Vedi [mandatario](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI09/GDLI_09_ocr_632.pdf&parola=mandatario). `Mandatorio` non è presente nel GDLI, ma io lo comprendo indicare un obbligo per il mandatario in quanto compreso nel mandato del mandante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sono d'accordo con te, la parola giusta da usare è ***obbligatorio***, in quanto anche la Treccani indica [mandatorio](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/mandatorio-significato-storia-usi/27369) come un neologismo.

Mandatorio deriva da ***mandato*** che a sua volta proviene dal latino ***mandatum*** che significava mandare cioè "**affidare**".

Il mandato in ambito legale indica l'esercizio di un atto legale per conto di un mandante.

**Aggiornamento 09/2023**

In questo interessante articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca denominato ***[Mandatorio: significato, storia, usi](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/mandatorio-significato-storia-usi/27369)*** vengono spiegati molti aspetti interessanti

> Alcuni lettori chiedono chiarimenti in merito all’aggettivo mandatorio usato con il senso di ‘obbligatorio’: se è ammissibile nella lingua italiana, se è proprio solo di determinati linguaggi specialistici, e se deriva dall’inglese mandatory.

Comment: Un orrendo inglesismo come _assolutamente_ in luogo di _certamente_.

Comment: Più che un "orrendo inglesismo" o un "neologismo", si tratta di un termine desueto. Il suo uso era più frequente al tempo dell'Unità d'Italia rispetto ad oggi, come riporta Google n-gram. Ho dovuto accorciare il link, ma questo è il grafico. https://is.gd/Cd2jYF

Answer (score 1):

Non si tratta assolutamente di un neologismo né di un inglesismo: trattasi di termine desueto, oggi dall'area di applicazione molto ristretta (la giurisprudenza), al di fuori della quale suona come un tecnicismo forse un po' forzato.

Comment: Sarà, ma il Grande Dizionario della lingua italiana lo classifica solo in un supplemento del 2009. Qualche citazione sarebbe necessaria. E, da quello che vedo su Google books, il significato è diverso da quello attuale calcato dall'inglese.

Comment: Credo che abbia raggione damenpra. V.  https://unaparolaalgiorno.it/significato/mandatorio  o anche https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_519.html